# script somente em tags visiveis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contador

Quero que o script faça a contagem apenas das tags `<li>` que estão visíveis, mas o código abaixo faz a contagem mesmo com `display:none`.

Existe alguma coisa que faça isso?

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```js
  $( ".rodapeUlCat" ).append( $( "<li>" ) );
var n = $( ".rodapeUlCat li" ).length;
$( ".rodapeCat" ).text( " categorias( " + n + " )" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="rodapeUlCat margin-top-25">
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li style="display:none"><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="rodapeCat"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o seletor [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

```
$( ".rodapeUlCat li:visible" ).length
```

No caso das ocultas, existe o [`:hidden`](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

#### DEMO

```js
 $(".rodapeUlCat").append($("<li>"));
 var n = $(".rodapeUlCat li:visible").length;
 $(".rodapeCat").text(" categorias( " + n + " )");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="rodapeUlCat margin-top-25">
  <li>
    <h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li style="display:none">
    <h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="rodapeCat"></div>
```